# Making SQL Query

Tags: sql, hive

INPUT DATA

```
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| country | tgtschema_name | tablename | tgttableversion | col_function | flag |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| zz      | abc_zz         | table1    | 01              | TBD1         | no   |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| bs      | abc_bs         | table2    | 01              | TBD1         | yes  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| bs      | abc_bs         | table3    | 01              | TBD1         | yes  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| bs      | abc_bs         | table4    | 01              | TBD1         | yes  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| bs      | abc_bs         | table4    | 02              | TBD2         | no   |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| do      | abc_do         | table5    | 01              | TBD1         | yes  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| do      | abc_do         | table6    | 01              | TBD1         | yes  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| do      | abc_do         | table7    | 01              | TBD1         | yes  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
```

OUTPUT REQUIRED DATA

```
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| country | tgtschema_name | tablename | tgttableversion | col_function | flag |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| zz      | abc_zz         | table1    | 01              | TBD1         | no   |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| bs      | abc_bs         | table2    | 01              | TBD1         | yes  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| bs      | abc_bs         | table3    | 01              | TBD1         | yes  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| bs      | abc_bs         | table4    | 02              | TBD2         | no   |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| do      | abc_do         | table5    | 01              | TBD1         | yes  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| do      | abc_do         | table6    | 01              | TBD1         | yes  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
| do      | abc_do         | table7    | 01              | TBD1         | yes  |
+---------+----------------+-----------+-----------------+--------------+------+
```

If I have more than one record in country, *tgtschema_name* and *tablename* columns then I need to have a record for which flag is "No".

Comment: Its Hive database

Answer (score 0):

edit: Answer was provided without knowing the specific db.

Something like this should work assuming you have id field:

```
select * 
from t t1 
where not exists (
  select country 
  from t t2 
  where t1.id != t2.id
     t1.country = t2.country and 
     (...add the rest here...) and 
     t2.flag = 'No'
)
```

The idea is that you get all data except if you have the second entry with the same attributes by with flag 'No' you wish to omit the other one.

Comment: I have included a ID(Sequence Number) Column in Input.  After executing, I am getting below error: "Line 6:8 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'id': SubQuery expression refers to both Parent and SubQuery expressions and is not a valid join condition."

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it with Hive, as it provides HiveQL, but maybe you can make left join and exclude those which some elements found if not exists does not work?